# MSAL fails with iOS simulator 13 Scheme msauthv2 for broker not present

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I've downloaded same code from [MSAL sample iOS code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2/archive/master.zip)

This seems to be working with iOS11 simulator but when i change target to iOS13, it doesn't open authentication just keep asking to open authentication view in loop.

App is configured with all the settings required to support iOS13 and below are the logs i see when app runs

**Requiring default broker type due to app being built with iOS 13 SDK**(Even if i reset simulator, this won't works)
**Scheme msauthv2 for broker not present**

I cannot understand above log, what broker app is searching for?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. What did you do ?